# Is it social engineering when you know you are being social engineered?

Tags: social-engineering

More like a philosophical question.

Comment: I think what you mean to ask was "can it still be called 'trickery' if I know I am being tricked?". But "social engineering" is more than trickery.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

If you know you are being cheated, you are still being cheated. For social engineering, this may mean that you are warned, and that the attempt will probably fail. But social engineering in itself does not guarantee a positive outcome: a failed attempt is still social engineering.

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be understood in different ways.

If the question is "**Am I still social engineering someone if he knows he's being *social engineered*?**", then I guess [@Ljm Dullaart answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/207588/203666) is what you're looking for.

Otherwise, if your question is "**Could the fact that I know that I'm being social engineered be a way to social engineer the other person?**" then **absolutely yes**: knowing that someone is lying to you is an advantage that, generally speaking, could let you gain additional information about the person you're talking with or the facts you want to know about.